# Run PHP array inside php $tag = "";

Tags: php, html

I try to run the **file_get_contents** inside my php $tag but its not working, hope you can tell me why.

I need to include 3 contents sufflet in my array in my $linkcontent after that will it be send to overwrite another .php document later!

But the content from the **file_get_contents** does not run correctly.

```
if ($content_type == '1') {
            $linkcontent = "

   $homepageheader

   <meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"http://$directory\"/>
   <meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"$billedeurl\" />
   <br>

   $homepage2<br>
   $homepage3<br>
   $homepage4<br>

   $homepagefooter
   "; 
   }else{

   $linkcontent = "

   $homepageheader

   <meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"http://$directory\"/>

   <meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"$billedeurl\" />
   <br>


   $first = 'xxxx/2.php';
   $second = 'xxxx/3.php';
   $third = 'xxxx/4.php';

   $array = array($first, $second, $third);
   shuffle($array);

   foreach($array as $el) {
   file_get_contents($el);
   }
   ;"; 


    }
```

Comment: don't use PHP and PHP functions in double quotes.

Comment: i need to do it to write my script.

Comment: What do you have inside those php files? HTML or php?

Answer (score -1):

Try using require instead of file_get_contents. 
Using require, the files you include will be interpreted as PHP files.